# I am unable to execute Selenium with sikuli script in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, sikuli

I am unable to execute selenium scripts which involve sikuli in Jenkins.

I am using Maven project. OS is Ubuntu.

Can someone help me on how to execute selenium script with sikuli in Jenkins?

I am not getting any errors in Jenkins console output

I have attached Jenkins output below.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExpertusONE_4.5</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExpertusONE_4.5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExpertusONE_4.5</name>
    <description>ExpertusONE_4.5</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <includes>
                        <include>CreateOrganization.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>/home/nivedab/ExpertusONE_4.5/Manage_Suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>


    </build>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8.0_222</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

[image: Jenkins Console Output]